# How long does it take for a visit to a page appears in the report?

Tags: google-analytics

In the `Realtime overview` page of GA4 I see there are pages that are being viewed. However, after a while these pages don't appear in the reports. Is there anything that I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data refreshes happen every 8 to 12 hours. Once they happen, the data should be available in the Explorer reports. If you nee more real time reporting, you will need to link your property to BigQuery.

Comment: do you have any idea why it cannot refresh sooner?

Comment: This is just Google's decision. I suspect they want people to either leverage their BigQuery in an attempt to getoney from users and or built in better data refresh intervals in their 360 product.